# have anyone work on xcrud

Tags: php, join

i have two table  subject_list  and questions
 subjectId is foreign key in question table.

i am displaying subject table using xcrud, and also
 i want to count number of question in  particular subject which will come from question table.

```
$this->load->library('loadxcrud');
echo Xcrud::load_css();

$xcrud = Xcrud::get_instance();
$xcrud->table('subject_list');
$xcrud->columns("subject_name,description,id");
$xcrud->fields("subject_name,description");
$xcrud->label("id", "No. of questions");
//$xcrud->join('id','question_details','subject_id');
$xcrud->before_insert('checksubjectexist');
$xcrud->before_update('checksubjectexistupdate');
$xcrud->pass_var("entry_by", 1);
$xcrud->validation_required('subject_name,description');

$xcrud->limit(5);
$xcrud->unset_edit(FALSE);
$xcrud->unset_add(FALSE);
$xcrud->unset_view(FALSE);
$xcrud->unset_print(FALSE);
$xcrud->unset_csv(TRUE);
$xcrud->unset_search(FALSE);
$xcrud->unset_title(TRUE);
$xcrud->unset_remove(TRUE);
echo $xcrud->render();
```

please help me if you can

Answer (score 3):

You can use subselect.

```
$xcrud->subselect( 'Questions', 'SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM questions q WHERE q.subjectId = {id}' );
$xcrud->columns("subject_name,description,id,Questions");
```